# Does the angular service always maintain a single tone?

Tags: angular, typescript, service

I'm curious about the service structure of angular.
For example, suppose you have modules for each function, and you have one service file for each module. If there is a code that uses the same auth api in each module service, is the auth status of service a of module a and service b of module b properly shared? On the contrary, there is only one auth service corresponding to auth api, and I wonder if it works exactly the same as when importing and using the service from each module.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angular it is important that where do you provide a service.
providing creates a new instance of that service.
If you provide the service at root, the whole application access the same service instance, but if you provide it in a component, that component tree will reach the same instance.
see [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/providers#:%7E:text=Providing%20a%20service,link)